# Binding StickNFind for Xamarin fails to compile

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to make a binding for StickNFind to use in a Xamarin-based project.

The problematic class is `LeDeviceManager`, it inherits `CBCentralManagerDelegate`, which is an abstract class and the `UpdateState(m)` method is not a part of the binding.

Here's the Obj-C header for this class:

```
interface LeDeviceManager : NSObject <CBCentralManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *devList;
@property (nonatomic)        CBCentralManager *btmgr;
@property (nonatomic,strong) id <LeDeviceManagerDelegate> delegate;

- (id)      initWithSupportedDevices: (NSArray *) devCls delegate: (id <LeDeviceManagerDelegate>) del;
- (void)    startScan;
- (void)    stopScan;

@end
```

And this is the binding I've come up with, with Objective Sharpie's heavy assistance:

```
    [Model, BaseType (typeof(CBCentralManagerDelegate))]
    public partial interface LeDeviceManager
    {
        [Export ("devList", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        NSMutableArray DevList { get; set; }

        [Export ("btmgr")]
        CBCentralManager Btmgr { get; set; }

        [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        LeDeviceManagerDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

        [Export ("initWithSupportedDevices:delegate:")]
        IntPtr Constructor (NSObject[] devCls, LeDeviceManagerDelegate del);

        [Export ("startScan")]
        void StartScan ();

        [Export ("stopScan")]
        void StopScan ();

        [Export ("UpdatedState")] 
        [New] // Added as suggested by another SO post, also tried [Abstract]
        void UpdatedState(CBCentralManager mgr);
    }
```

And I get this error:
 Error CS0533: `StickNFind.LeDeviceManager.UpdatedState(MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManager)' hides inherited abstract member`MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManagerDelegate.UpdatedState(MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManager)' (CS0533) (SNF_Binding)

How do I fix this:

Comment: did you finish this binding?  I need the same thing and prefer not reinvent the wheel if you've already done it.

Comment: I did manage to get it past that error but then I got another error about some duplicate names in SNF SDK and I gave up. I went through a whole lot of trouble with SNF and I don't recommend them - all of their code is really crappy, the beacons behave unpredictably and I could never make them work, their support is abysmal.

Answer (score 1):

Hello can you try this instead?

```
[Protocol] // Added Protocol attribute
[Model]
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))] //Changed BaseType to NSObject
public partial interface LeDeviceManager : ICBCentralManagerDelegate
{
    [Export ("devList", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    NSMutableArray DevList { get; set; }

    [Export ("btmgr")]
    CBCentralManager Btmgr { get; set; }

    [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    LeDeviceManagerDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("initWithSupportedDevices:delegate:")]
    IntPtr Constructor (NSObject[] devCls, LeDeviceManagerDelegate del);

    [Export ("startScan")]
    void StartScan ();

    [Export ("stopScan")]
    void StopScan ();

    [Export ("updatedState")] [New] // Notice I changed UpdatedState to updatedState lowercase u
    void UpdatedState(CBCentralManager mgr);
}
```

I highly recommend reading Binding Protocols section of [this doc](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs)